# Como mudar a cor do cursor de texto sem mudar a cor da fonte

Tags: css, css3

Alguém sabe como mudar a cor do cursor de inserção de texto (A barrinha que fica piscando quando estamos escrevendo algo em um input) sem mudar a cor da fonte?

[image: Barra de inserção]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para mudar a cor do *cursor de texto* ou conhecido também por *acento circunflexo de inserção*, você pode usar a propriedade [caret-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) no elemento que você deseja que a cor seja alterada, assim essa propriedade não vai afetar diretamente o texto do elemento, mas sim, apenas o cursor de texto:

```css
input {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px
}

.input1 {
  caret-color: red;
}

.input2 {
  caret-color: blue;
}

.input3 {
  caret-color: orange;
}

.input4 {
  caret-color: yellow;
}

.input5 {
  caret-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<input class="input1" type="text" placeholder="Vermelho:">
<input class="input2" type="text" placeholder="Azul:">
<input class="input3" type="text" placeholder="Laranja:">
<input class="input4" type="text" placeholder="Amarelo:">
<input class="input5" type="text" placeholder="Violeta:">
```